# mongodb query: $size with $gt returns always 0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I wonder what can I do to enable inequalities on the size of arrays in mongodb queries.

For example, I have the following two queries:

```
> db.userStats.count({sessions:{$size:1}})
1381
> db.userStats.count({sessions:{$size:{$gt:0}}})
0
```

If `$gt` worked as I intend the result would be different for the second query, leading to a number that is at least 1381.

What is wrong with the second query and how can I fix it to achieve the result I want?

thanks

Answer (score 11):

You cannot do that as is actually referenced in the documentation for [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/). So that operator alone evaluates a "literal" result and **cannot** be use in conjunction with "range operators" such as you are asking.

Your only real options are to ask for a "size" that is "not equal to 0" by negating the condition with the [**`$not`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator. Which is perfectly valid:

```js
db.userStats.count({ "sessions": { "$not": { "$size": 0 } } });
```

Or otherwise test with the other incarnation of [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) in the aggregation framework, as long as your MongoDB version is 2.6 or greater:

```js
db.userStats.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
         "_id": null,
         "count": {
             "$sum": {
                 "$cond": [
                     { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$sessions", 0 } ] },
                     1,
                     0
                 ]
             }
         }
    }}
])
```

Possibly also with the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) form of JavaScript evaluation:

```js
db.userStats.count(function() { return this.sessions.length > 0 });
```

But likely slower than the last version.

Or in fact you can just do this with ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation), and the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator:

```js
db.userStats.count({ "sesssions.0": { "$exists": true } });
```

As the general idea is that if there is an element at the index `0` then the array has some length.

It all depends on your approach, but any of these forms gets the right result.

But for the "best" performance from MongoDB, don't use **any** of these methods. Instead, keep the array "length" as a property of the document you are inspecting. This you can "index" and the queries issued can actually access that index, which none of the above can do.

Maintain it like this:

```js
db.userStats.update(
     { "_id": docId, "sessions": { "$ne": newItem } },
     {
         "$push": { "sessions": newItem },
         "$inc": { "countSessions": 1 }
     }
)
```

Or to remove:

```js
db.userStats.update(
     { "_id": docId, "sessions": newItem  },
     {
         "$pull": { "sessions": newItem },
         "$inc": { "countSessions": -1 }
     }
)
```

Then you can just query on "countSesssions" which can also index for best performance:

```js
db.userStats.find({ "countSessions": { "$gt": 0 } })
```

And that is the "best" way to do it.

Comment: actually, `{$gt:0}` was just an example, I meant a parametrizable one, so the ad-hoc solution for the 0 case is not good enough, unfortunately. The problem is that I have a system for automatic generation of queries to be used with `find`. After seeing this limitation of mongo the implementation of the inequality becomes context-dependent, which will make my code even more complicated. Interesting your suggestion of `$exists`, tough.

Comment: @francescostablum Interesting that I note the documentation seems have changed, where there was a previous statement saying that operators such as `$gt` or other in-equality operators do not work in tandem. So Hmm, major oversight there. But also worth mentioning is that none of these operators can in fact work with an "index" to get the best performance from such a query. So where this is regularly needed, the "recommended" approach is to keep a field in your document that "tracks" the array length. I'll update with some more info on this.

Answer (score 2):

$size does not accept a range of value. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/

To select $size for a range of value, for example from 1 to 3, you may use $or

```
db.userStats.count( { $or: [ {sessions:{$size:1}}, {sessions:{$size:2}}, {sessions:{$size:3}} ] } )
```

Certainly, $or is a working but not good solution. Do as MongoDB suggests:

> To select documents based on fields with different numbers of
>   elements, create a counter field that you increment when you add
>   elements to a field.

Comment: hmm, this seems quite a severe limitation of Mongodb