# API Get method to get all tweets with hashtag count greater than within MongoDB in JSON format

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a MongoDB database that contains a number of tweets. I want to be able to get all the tweets in JSON list through my API that contain a number of hashtags greather than that specified by the user in the url (eg http://localhost:5000/tweets?morethan=5, which is 5 in this case) .

The hashtags are contained inside the entities column in the database, along with other columns such as user_mentions, urls, symbols and media. Here is the code I've written so far but doesnt return anything.

```
#!flask/bin/python

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/tweets', methods=['GET'])
def get_tweets():
# Connect to database and pull back collections

db = client['mongo']
collection = db['collection']

parameter = request.args.get('morethan')

if parameter:
    gt_parameter = int(parameter) + 1  # question said greater than not greater or equal
    key_im_looking_for = "entities.hashtags.{}".format(gt_parameter)  # create the namespace#
    cursor = collection.find({key_im_looking_for: {"$exists": True}})
```

EDIT: IT WORKS!

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? Can u give some feedback if something is wrong?

Comment: I didn't downvote but a word of warning that the more tags you apply to a question pulls needless attention from other communities and may draw negative feedback.  You are using flask and using an API, but the members of those communities are unlikely to be able to help you craft a better query and probably don't appreciate the question being tagged at them

Comment: I didn't downvote the question yet either, but there are a few things that are bad. Firstly, the amount of code. You should rather aim at extracting a [mcve]. Also, your statement that "I was thinking that I need to ...". Why? For what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in question is this line

```
cursor = collection.find({"entities": {"hashtags": parameter}})
```

This answer explains why it is impossible to directly perform what you ask.

[mongodb query: $size with $gt returns always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159975/mongodb-query-size-with-gt-returns-always-0#26160134)

That answer also describes potential (but poor) ideas to get around it.

The best suggestion is to modify all your documents and put a "num_hashtags" key in somewhere, index that, and query against it.

Using [The Twitter JSON API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json.html) you could update all your documents and put a the num_hashtags key in the entities document.

Alternatively, you **could** solve your immediate problem by doing a very slow full table scan across all documents for **every query** checking if the hashtag number which is one greater than your parameter exists by abusing [MongoDB Dot Notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation).

```
gt_parameter = int(parameter) + 1  # question said greater than not greater or equal
key_im_looking_for = "entities.hashtags.{}".format(gt_parameter)  #create the namespace# 
# py2.7 => key_im_looking_for = "entities.hashtags.%s" %(gt_parameter) 
# in this example it would be "entities.hashtags.6"
cursor = collection.find({key_im_looking_for: {"$exists": True}})
```

The **best** answer (and the key reason to use a NoSQL database in the first place) is that you should modify your data to suit your retrieval. If possible, you should perform an inplace update adding the num_hashtags key.

Comment: I tried using your second alternative but it doesn't seem to work. I will edit my question to show you.

Comment: It actually works! There were just no tweets with more than 6 hashtags to find and the numbering of hashtags begins from 0 so there is no need for the +1.